# Vue CLI Child compilation failed after first build unless I clear .cache folder

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, vue-cli-3

The title of the question says it all really.

I'm using Vue CLI and the project compiles fine the first time. But if I try to build it again it fails with this error:

```
Error: Child compilation failed:
  Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\Oliver\Workspace\academy-residences\public\index.html' in 'C:\Users\Oliver\Workspace\academy-residences':
  Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\Oliver\Workspace\academy-residences\public\index.html' in 'C:\Users\Oliver\Workspace\academy-residences'

  - compiler.js:79 childCompiler.runAsChild
    [academy-residences]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:79:16

  - Compiler.js:300 compile
    [academy-residences]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:300:11

  - Compiler.js:556 hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err
    [academy-residences]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:556:14


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [academy-residences]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compiler.js:553 compilation.seal.err
    [academy-residences]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:553:30


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [academy-residences]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compilation.js:1323 hooks.optimizeAssets.callAsync.err
    [academy-residences]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1323:35


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [academy-residences]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compilation.js:1314 hooks.optimizeChunkAssets.callAsync.err
    [academy-residences]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1314:32


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [academy-residences]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compilation.js:1309 hooks.additionalAssets.callAsync.err
    [academy-residences]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1309:36



[copy-webpack-plugin] unable to locate 'C:\Users\Oliver\Workspace\academy-residences\public' at 'C:\Users\Oliver\Workspace\academy-residences\public'
 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! academy-residences@0.1.0 watch: `vue-cli-service build --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
```

However, if I delete the `.cache` folder in `node_modules` then it builds correctly again!

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "academy-residences",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "watch": "vue-cli-service build --watch",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "heroku-postbuild": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "element-ui": "^2.4.5",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.21",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.20",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-element": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  }
}
```

and here is my vue.config

```
module.exports = {
    outputDir: './public',

    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '' : '',

    configureWebpack: {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@': __dirname + '/ui/src'
            }
        },
        entry: {
            app: './ui/src/main.js'
        }
    }
};
```

package.json sits in the root folder of the project with all the vue source code in ui

```
root/
  ui/
    src/
  node_modules/
  package.json
```

This is a recent problem. The other day everything was working fine. The only things that I think could have caused this is deleting @vue/cli and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 2):

> This is a recent problem. The other day everything was working fine.
>   The only things that I think could have caused this is deleting
>   @vue/cli and reinstalling it.

Well, you're right about this. Until mid-2018 I used to have a folder structure like

```
project
 ├── config
 ├── src // components, router, etc
 ├── static // images, robots.txt manifest, vendor css and whatnot
 ├── dist // not under version control, generated at deploy time
 └── index.html // entry point
```

When building the project, the `dist` folder was wiped clean, then the chunks coming from `src` where compiled into it, then the static files under `static` copied over to `dist` (This one might happen before compiling the src files, whatever).

My config looked like:

```
 new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ]),
```

Where `config.build.assetsSubDirectory` was `dist`.

Fast forward to current @vue/cli  (as of March 2019), the template now uses webpack@4 instead of webpack@3, and some defaults have changed. Specifically, they expect the structure to be:

```
project
 ├── config
 ├── src 
 ├── public //  <── WHAIT!!! NO LONGER CALLED "static"
 |   └── index.html // <── NO LONGER IN ROOT
 └── dist
```

So in your config, declaring

```
module.exports = {
    outputDir: './public',
    ...
}
```

Means you're wiping `public` at buildtime, then webpack cannot copy your public assets from its default asset source to the output folder, which became the same.

Now, if you inspect what is webpack actually doing (from your project root folder)

```
vuw inspect > output.js
```

or

```
$(npm bin)/vue-cli-service > output.js
```

You will see `output.js` has a block in the likes of:

```
/* config.plugin('copy') */
new CopyWebpackPlugin(
  [
    {
      from: '/home/user/project/public',
      to: '/home/user/project/dist',
      toType: 'dir',
      ignore: [
        '.DS_Store'
      ]
    }
  ]
),
```

If I changed my `vue.config.js` to have, as you have

```
outputDir: "./public",
```

The latter command would output a section saying:

```
/* config.plugin('copy') */
new CopyWebpackPlugin(
  [
    {
      from: '/home/user/project/public',
      to: '/home/user/project/public',
      toType: 'dir',
      ignore: [
        '.DS_Store'
      ]
    }
  ]
),
```

Which obviously make no sense whatsoever

## TL/DR;

Don't use `public` as output folder, or find a way to change the static assets folder, for which I believe you have to manually configure `CopyWebpackPlugin` in your vue config file.